# A clarification on collecting the values from a for loop

Tags: python

I have a for loop(In Python) and I compute an `xk` value at the end of each iteration.(This is an approximation to a local minimum)

My question is, At the end of each iteration, I need to compare this `xk` value and the one obtained by the previous iteration. (To see whether their difference is less than the given tolerance).

I know that one way to do this is to collect all the `xk` values to an array and compare them. But it will be a waste of memory because we only need the last two.
So may I know whether there is a better way to store only the last two values by replacing the previous ones. Hence in that way I will only need an array with two elements.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Could you please provide both an example, expected output and the code you have tried to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
previous_value = None # or some value that doesn't normally occur
while True:
    value = .....
    if previous_value is not None:
         .... do what you need to do..... 
         .... maybe break out of the loop
    previous_value = value
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't just want to collect all values: `itertools.accumulate`

```
from itertools import accumulate

def some_calculation(n):
    return n

def func(last_calculated, current):
        return current_cal if (current_cal := some_calculation(current)) > last_calculated else last_calculated

for val in accumulate(range(5), func):
    print(val)
```

This apply function in cumulative way, i.e.:

```
accumulate([1, 2, 3], func)
```

Will be

```
last = func(0, 1)
last = func(last, 2)
last = func(last, 3)
```

Use `generator` instead if you need more control - i.e. number of items to remember:

```
def some_calculation(n):
    return n

def calculate_gen(list_):
    last_1, last_2 = 0, 0
    for current in list_:
        calculated = some_calculation(current)

        yield last_2, last_1, calculated

        last_1, last_2 = calculated, last_1
```

or

```
from collections import deque

def calculate_gen_deque(list_, items_to_remember: int):
    last = deque([0 for _ in range(items_to_remember)])
    for current in list_:
        calculated = some_calculation(current)

        yield last.popleft(), *last, calculated  # from oldest to newest

        last.append(calculated)
```

Choose and change stuffs behind `yield` up to your taste. Pass those to derivation comparing function, maybe?